# Optimizing and organizing ASP.NET content

Tags: asp.net, optimization, organization

I have a new ASP.NET Web Forms project that was started about 6 months ago. Being as how the project is still fairly new and in its infancy, this hasn't been much of a problem till recently.

The application is an ASP.NET Web Form application with a C# and SQL Server back end and an HTML5 and jQuery front end. The application is mostly ajax powered with very little post backs. It consists of mostly jQuery ajax calls to C# WebMethods.

The problem I am running into is some of my aspx pages are over 50kb in size with all the javascript and jQuery that is in the aspx page. I would like to move a lot of this javascript and jQuery code into separate files, but most of it consists of code that use the aspx `<%= %>` tags, which makes moving it a difficult (if not impossible) task.

It is getting tedious to find things in the code. I am wondering if there is a way to optimize the code (by somehow reducing the size of the aspx file) and if there is a good way to keep all this jQuery and javascript organized better so that finding things are a little bit easier? Also, is there maybe a javascript minifier that will minify the javascript inside an aspx page?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using AJAX, I'm assuming you're using HTML markup, not any of the web controls. If so, one thing you can do is trun of ViewState in the aspx page.  I was in the same position a few years ago, and decided to switch the Asp.net MVC.  I would recommend you look into that.  It gives you a much better development model, with minimal overhead.

Also, is you JS/CSS minified?  I'm still confused about why "...but most of it consists of code that use the aspx <%= %> tags, which makes moving it a difficult (if not impossible) task."

WebForms, like MVC, also now supports bundling and minifications of JS files, check this out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx

**Update**: As OP pointed out, for .Net 3.5, you can use http://getcassette.net/ for bundling and minification.

Comment: Yes, my external CSS and JS is minified. However, I can't find a minifier that will minify the JS inside my aspx pages. The reason for all the `<%= %>` tags is because I'll have an asp.net button for example and then i'll have jquery code such as: `$('#<%= btnOkay %>').button();`. Or I might need to get the value of a drop down: `$('#<%= ddlStateName %>').val();`. A lot of code like that.

Comment: One thing you can do is put all the control ids on the aspx page: var ddlStateName = '#<%= ddlStateName %>';.  Then reference these in your separate JS files: $(ddlStateName ).val(). This isn't the best approach, but it will help move the JS out of the ASPX page.

Comment: This is a good idea and I actually thought about this. The problem is, I feel like I'd have a bunch of javascript functions contained in an external javascript file (which is good), but I feel like if I need to go back and change something later, I'd have to hunt and search for where it needs to be changed, if that makes any sense.

Comment: It should be fine as long as you have your JavaScript properly organized.  For instance JavaScript functions specific to one page show go to a javascript file with that page's name.  All shared functions can go into a separate file.  You can then use http://getcassette.net/ to properly minify and bundle all those files, which would of course happen on release.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid using <% %> in your js to be able to reference your controls you can set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to "static", that way the ID you set for the controls is the one that will be rendered and in js you can reference the control with something like

asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStateName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static"></DropdownList>
```

jquery

```
$("#ddlStateName").val();
```

Comment: This would be a very good idea except, from what I understand, static ClientIdMode's are only available in .NET 4.0 and later? My project is using .NET 3.5.

Comment: Yes ClientIdMode is 4.0 and up only.